# failed to export dmp file oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle12c, rdbms

[console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1w9A.png)I am using oracle 12c in docker from a mac terminal and I just could not find a way to export dmp file for my database.

> EXP-00028: failed to open /Users/benson/Desktop/Prac1.dmp for write

Comment: This is generally a permission issue. Please share the whole error message and your command which you used to export.

Comment: `HOST EXP USERNAME/PASSWORD file=/Users/benson/Desktop/Prac1.dmp owner=USERNAME `

Comment: Why you are using `HOST` command? You can directly use `EXP` in console. No need to execute `EXP` from sql*plus. Also, you can use `expdp` instead of `exp`. Also share whole error message.

Comment: I was instructed to do so (just started learning oracle this semester). I am not sure how to execute EXP from the command since it returns `-bash: exp: command not found`.  Added image"console message".

Comment: It simply means that the Your DB user do not have permission on folder where you are trying to export.